# Email Template Validation

Tags: zurb-foundation, html-email

I am sending transnational emails, I download a template from Zurb foundation but the problem that this template is not showing correctly as I expected. I validated the HTML using W3C and it is valid yet it is not showing correctly.

You can have a look at the template on http://52fluent.com/email.html

The main problem that the gray bar up is always trimmed as if there is no styling what so ever is implemented

How can I find the problem and what tools to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the template relies on a link to the CSS stylesheet at http://52fluent.com/email.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://52fluent.com/email.css" />
```

Such a link does not work in email. You need to copy the styles from that CSS file onto each of the appropriate HTML elements in the template, for example:

```
<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#999999"
    style="margin: 0; padding: 0; [...etc...]">
```

Of course, there are tools to do that automatically: for example, a quick Google search turned up a [CSS Inline Transformer](http://tikku.com/css-inline-transformer). There’s also a Python library called [premailer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer/).

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that error and the python tools looks great